Is there easily achievable debugging from Visual Studio with multiple symbols (stripped vs full)?
We're releasing an application to public, in which we don't want to include full symbols. So we're stripping them as mentioned in official docs (Debugging with symbols, PDBstripped). Both full and stripped symbols are correctly generated, we store full symbols in private location (share drive) and ship the product with stripped ones. So far all good.
Issue happens when we want to debug released app (i.e. crashdump) - we open the dump from Visual Studio and it automatically loads local symbols inclided with the application (the stripped version). Once we remove those (delete local pdbs), it will start searching the network path and properly loads correct full symbols from there = all that because local symbols weren't found.
Attaching generic VS's Options form, we're having our path correctly specified below "Microsoft Symbol Servers" and works:

Is there any way to override the behavior and load full symbols with priority? I.e. give local symbols lower priority than the ones from network location? Or can we somehow force search loading on network location when we have just stripped symbols?

I don't use Visual Studio, but I believe you should be able to set your full symbol file to "Always Load Automatically".

It might be running in a problem that some symbls aren't present (e.f. from dependency DLL). When I played with these (mind you, it was Vs2010 time) I had a problem with going into Qt framework code, all symbols had to be present at same location or else. I ended up making soft links to smbol files files in Qt folder

@SirNate I'm worried that this option is applicable only for one particular symbol file on exact path. But it won't search the symbol store for the file we want, which would be with each build different.

@Swift-FridayPie as mentioned in the original question, everything is working as expected - stripped symbols correctly loaded AND full symbols also, when we remove the stripped ones. I'm just looking for approach how to automatize this / if the VS can handle it iself or we must manually remove stripped file everytime.

You always can run scripts as a post-build event

Question:

Can we somehow force search loading on network location when we have
just stripped symbols?

Short answer:

Yes, "Visual Studio 2022" does just that. If it cannot find the full
symbol file in the executable file path, it searches for the search
paths specified in the "Symbols" section of "Debug Options" (Symbol file (.pdb) locations).

To test, we perform the following steps (As you know):

1- Create a "C++ Console App" project in "Visual Studio 2022".
2- Put the following code in the main file.

ConsoleApplicationCppPDB.cpp:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    throw std::invalid_argument("It is an exception!");
}


3- In the Properties form for the project, specify the names of two
symbol files in the "Linker" section.



4- In the "Options" submenu of "Debug", add the network path as a search path in "Symbol file (.pdb) locations", so that if "Visual Studio" does not find full symbols PDB file, it
will search this path. We used the local folder path here, but a network path will probably work as well, as Microsoft explains here: "Type the URL (http), network share, or local path of the symbol server or symbol location"



5- Build the project and then run the project and when the exception
is displayed, create the dump file using the "Save Dump As..." submenu
from the "Debug" main menu.
6- Copy the two symbol files from the path of the executable file to
the search path "C:\[PDB]"
7- In the program path, delete the full symbols file so that only
strip symbols remain.
8- By double-clicking on the dump file, open it with "Visual Studio" and
use the "Debug with Native Only" operation. "Visual Studio" finds the
error line.
9- Remove the symbols file from the search path ("C:\[PDB]") and run the previous step again, "Visual Studio" can no longer find the error line. So the symbols PDB file was loaded from the search path.

Note 1:
The file name or path of full symbols and strip symbols must be different, otherwise an error will occur.
Note 2:
As you know, if possible, it's best not to give the client any symbol files if you don't want them to have the source code. In general, if the client gives us the dump file, we can debug according to the version of the client program and the PDB & EXE files and the source code (TFS or Git) that we have for that version. But maybe making a dump file with some tools also requires the PDB file.


The file name or path of full symbols and strip symbols must be different, otherwise an error will occur.

Oooh that's nasty, this is most likely the reason why it is not working for us - since we're keeping same naming for stripped and full symbols, just saving them to different location. (We're actually stripping them after; so the process is create full -> save those -> stripped them -> ship app with stripped).
We'll play around that and let you know. Thanks so far, that looks really promising!

@Tatranskymedved, I'm glad you found my post helpful. What I said was a review of what we know, and you know it yourself, but it is not bad to remember those things. Actually, I mean that if the name and path of the two symbol files are the same, during the build, Visual Studio will show the error message "Error LNK1212 error opening program database; file is in use" and the project build will fail. If you succeed in building, maybe the problem is somewhere else. In any case, thank you and I hope your problem will be solved soon.

If in the project settings, we put the path to create the main PDB somewhere other than the application folder, when displaying the exception or in other words when the application crashes, Visual Studio 2022 could not display the error correctly. It is better to create both files in the project folder, and then copy them to any other place you need using DOS commands in the "Command Line" section of "Post-Build Event" in the Properties form for the project.

According to the picture you posted in the question, I think you may not have set the network path correctly in Options ("Step 4" in my answer), maybe my guess is wrong. Please check the network path again.

That screenshot is just for "decorative purpose", we have proper path entered there.
Also, we are using symbol store (symstore), which is little bit complicating things as they are storing it in a structure which is based on the file names. And this then leads VS to not finding the symbols when we use different name (i.e. with _full suffix). But we're not loosing hope and playing around.

@Tatranskymedved, Well, it's good that you are aware of this issue. Any way you see fit is probably better, because you are more focused on the subject.

@Tatranskymedved, I thought of something. As you said, having the same name of both symbol files can be a problem, of course there is another reason!
Visual Studio may consider the stripped symbols as the original symbol file when loading the symbol file and will not search the symbol server. Then it is noticed that the loaded symbol file is incomplete.

@Tatranskymedved, The solution is to set the name of original symbol unchanged "$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb" so that it can be found on the server, only in the "Stripped Private Symbol" section, change the name of the stripped file, for example "$ (OutDir)$(TargetName)_Stripped.pdb", might solve the problem.

If I understand your situation correctly, you want to keep all debugging information on your build server, and make sure that no debugging information is to be found on the place where you installed your problem. Then your program crashes, and you wonder how to investigate that crash dump locally.
Big point: you want to be able to do this, but you don't want other people (like the customer) to be able to do this.
I have worked for a firm with another approach: a try .. except clause was written, enclosing the entire applications, causing, in case of a failing application (thread), the corresponding crash dump to be moved to some server in my firm, and every day, my first task was to perform crash analysis on all crash dumps on that server.
Like this, your customer won't try to investigate the crash dump and trying to figure out finding debugging symbols, ..., because he won't even realise his application has crashed (ok, it might be mentioned in the event logs, but there's no actual dump present).

Uhm, sorry, but that's not what I'm after. I'm trying to get an answer for the technical question here: with two version of symbols (full vs strip) and how to easily manage their loading; not trying to figure completely new approach for industry on "how to handle crashing", "symbol storing" or its "architecture" in general.

@Tatranskymedved: no problem, it was just a suggestion. Although my answer is not useful for you, I might just leave it here, maybe it might inspire other people.
